# Name of modules $E$ such that $-\otimes_RE$ reflects zero objects

Tags: modules, tensor-products

Let $R$ be ring and $E$ be a left $R$-module such that for every right $R$-module $M\otimes_RE=\{0\}$ implies $M=\{0\}$.
There is a particular name for $E$?

Comment: If $E$ is also flat, this condition is equivalent to being faithfully flat (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_module). I don't know if there's a name for this condition in the absence of flatness. Calling it "faithfulness" would of course be a bit confusing.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I'm interested when $E$ is not necessarily flat; can be called quasi-faithfulness?